# Neural Network producing NaN after first train

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorlayer

My neural network's outputs become all nan quickly after the first train. And all the costs are nan no matter how I modified learning rate. I have checked on Stack Overflow and other websites, and my problem falls into none of them. My network does produce correct (non-nan) output before any training. I am not sure if this is the problem of my input or my neural network becuase the neural network seems fine.

The input of my neural network are some features of machines, such as total plan quantities, total stock quantities, and etc. The output is ndividual plan quantities of how the total plan quantities of each machine will be distributed to other machines. My biggest concern is both the input and output have a lot of zeroes, because data take every forms and are not complete. I zero-filled all the gap to be able to put it inside a neural network. But even then I don't think the ntwork will produce nan after first train. Can anyone point out my problem? Below is my complete code:

```
#load data
ld = Loader()
X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = ld.load_data() * 3

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

#placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1306], name='x')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 508], name='y_')

#a single-layer neural network
net = tl.layers.InputLayer(x, name='input')
net = tl.layers.DenseLayer(net, n_units=1300, act=tf.nn.relu, name='relu1')
net = tl.layers.DenseLayer(net, n_units=508, act=None, name='output')

y = net.outputs
#cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_, logits=y, name='xentropy')
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_))

#train
n_epoch = 100
batch_size = 30
learning_rate = 10 ** -7
print_freq = 1
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

tl.layers.initialize_global_variables(sess)

net.print_params()
net.print_layers()

print('   learning_rate: %f' % learning_rate)
print('   batch_size: %d' % batch_size)

for epoch in range(n_epoch):
    start_time = time.time()
    for X_train_a, y_train_a in tl.iterate.minibatches(X_train, y_train, batch_size, shuffle=True):
        feed_dict = {x: X_train_a, y_: y_train_a}
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if epoch + 1 == 1 or (epoch + 1) % print_freq == 0:
        print("Epoch %d of %d took %fs"  % (epoch + 1, n_epoch, time.time() - start_time))
        train_loss, n_batch = 0, 0
        for X_train_a, y_train_a in tl.iterate.minibatches(X_train, y_train, batch_size, shuffle=True):
            feed_dict = {x: X_train_a, y_: y_train_a}
            err = sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed_dict)
            train_loss += err
            n_batch += 1
        print("   train loss: %f" % (train_loss / n_batch))

# Save model
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, "model/model.ckpt")
print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
tl.files.save_npz(net.all_params, name='model.npz')
sess.close()
```

Here is sample output:

[image: output]  [image: output-continued]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your input, any `NaN` or `inf` input will ruin the whole model.

Then, if the input is correct, I suggest you use TensorFlow debugger (read documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger)) to debug your model. In the documentation, there's a tutorial of how to debug the appearance of NaNs.

Comment: I printed out my input and you are correct. There is one inf among hundreds of data. It is very hard to spot. Now I find the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffreyYu No worries. You can easily check nan in a numpy array using [numpy.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), and numpy.isinf for inf

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The value returned by run() has the same shape as the fetches argument, where the leaves are replaced by the corresponding values returned by TensorFlow. 'fetches' can be arbitrary lists, tuples, namedtuple, dicts

So I guess your `err` variable is not an integer, so when you try to divide it with a number it returns `NaN`.

Comment: I use tf.reduce_mean so the err is an integer, but it's nan.